# T-SQL Table Name as parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I had this code that doesn't scale well since the table name is hard coded.
I would appreciate ideas about how to refactor it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIntRowVersion] (@Id INT, @Table NVARCHAR(128)) RETURNS BINARY(8) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @rowVersion AS BINARY(8)
   IF @Id = 0
      SELECT @rowVersion = 
      CASE
         WHEN @Table = 'Score' THEN (SELECT MAX([RowVersion]) FROM Score) 
         WHEN @Table = 'Department' THEN (SELECT MAX([RowVersion]) FROM Department)
         WHEN @Table = 'ContactType' THEN (SELECT MAX([RowVersion]) FROM ContactType)
         WHEN @Table = 'Region' THEN (SELECT MAX([RowVersion]) FROM Region)
      END
   ELSE
      SELECT @rowVersion = 
      CASE
         WHEN @Table = 'Score' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 [RowVersion] FROM Score WHERE Id = @Id) 
         WHEN @Table = 'Department' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 [RowVersion] FROM Department WHERE Id = @Id)
         WHEN @Table = 'ContactType' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 [RowVersion] FROM ContactType WHERE Id = @Id)
         WHEN @Table = 'Region' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 [RowVersion] FROM Region WHERE Id = @Id)
      END
RETURN @rowVersion
END

GO
```

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL and then execute it. You can't have a table name as a parameter as far as I am aware

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that must return a single, atomic value - it cannot be used to conditionally execute varying blocks of code - for that, you need to use `IF .. ELSE ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetIntRowVersion] 
(
    @Id INT
   ,@Table NVARCHAR(128)
)
AS
BEGIN;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @rowVersion AS BINARY(8);

    DECLARE @DynamicTSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

    IF @Id = 0 
        BEGIN;
            SET @DynamicTSQL = N'SELECT @rowVersion =   (SELECT MAX([RowVersion]) FROM ' + @Table + ')';
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN;
            SET @DynamicTSQL = N'SELECT @rowVersion =  (SELECT TOP 1 [RowVersion] FROM ' + quotename (@Table) + ' WHERE Id = ' + CAST(@Id AS VARCHAR(12)) +');';
        END;

    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQL, N'@rowVersion AS BINARY(8) OUTPUT', @rowVersion = @rowVersion OUTPUT;

    SELECT @rowVersion AS[rowVersion];

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    RETURN;
END;
```

You need to use stored procedure as the functions are not allowed to perform `CRUD` operations over SQL tables and execute dynamic T-SQL statements (unless being SQL CLR functions).

You can use `OUTPUT` parameter of the procedure, too.